# Services calls [/shadow_caster_material_name] and [/shadow_caster_render_back_faces] timed out, cannot use Gazebo

Tags: ros2, gazebo-11, ogre

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Setup: Ubuntu 20.04, ROS 2 Galactic, Gazebo (11.10.1-1~focal)

With the update to the gazebo11 (ver 11.10.1) in the last ROS 2 Galactic sync my launch files and Gazebo overall stopped working correctly (services are timed out).

After starting `gazebo --verbose` I got:

```
~$ gazebo --verbose
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.10.1
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.10.1
Copyright (C) 2012 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

[Msg] Waiting for master.
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.10.103
[Msg] Loading world file [/usr/share/gazebo-11/worlds/empty.world]
[Msg] Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
[Msg] Publicized address: 192.168.10.103
[Err] [Scene.cc:227] Service call[/shadow_caster_material_name] timed out
[Err] [Scene.cc:249] Service call[/shadow_caster_render_back_faces] timed out
[Wrn] [Scene.cc:462] Ignition transport [/scene_info] service call failed, falling back to gazebo transport [scene_info] request.
```

Reverting to the old version of Gazebo packages didn't help, but I am not sure if I did it correctly too (maybe I have missed some dependent ROS packages). I have used:

```
sudo apt-get install gazebo11=11.9.0-1~focal gazebo11-common=11.9.0-1~focal gazebo11-plugin-base=11.9.0-1~focal libgazebo11=11.9.0-1~focal libgazebo11-dev=11.9.0-1~focal
```

Gazebo and launcher still won't work even after that. I tried to reinstall everything, Gazebo, ROS2, my GPU drivers (latest recommended `nvidia-driver-510`).

It starts with `empty.world` scene, but any launcher (mine or from Nav2 repository and nav2_bringup package, branch" galactic, commit: 4bfedb8) cannot call any services.

When starting `gzserver --verbose` I am getting standard output, `gzclient --verbose` gives me every time the same timed-out error.

What is exactly happening? Does anybody have encountered this problem before? How can I solve it? Everything was working before...

I put this issue [there](https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/3173) already + I haven't found anything more than some  issues of the problems with Ogre3d about this kind of services timing out...

- https://github.com/osrf/gazebo/issues/2700
- https://githubmemory.com/index.php/repo/lopsided98/nix-ros-overlay/issues/161
- https://github.com/conda-forge/libignition-gazebo-feedstock/issues/6

There is my `ogre.log` too: https://controlc.com/9061c918

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27833/services-calls-%5B/shadow_caster_material_name%5D-and-%5B/shadow_caster_render_back_faces%5D-timed-out,-cannot-use-gazebo/) by [ljaniec](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/62948/ljaniec/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There was an update to the Gazebo 11 and luckily I found out what a solution - I had to reset the Firewall settings in Ubuntu 20.04 because even `ros2 topic list` started to not working correctly.

Then I tried to run `gazebo --verbose` and it didn't hanged, I could add TB3 to the empty world and see it's topics etc. I think the firewall was disabling the `ign-services` in the background and they timed-out every time..? Or something similar.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/62948/ljaniec/) with karma: 1 on 2022-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0